# Removing a string using Sed replace pattern

Tags: unix, sed

I want to replace unwanted strings using **unix sed reqular expression**

**Input string**

```
echo ',"wanted1":"value1","unwanted";"unwanted";"wanted2":"value2",'
```

**Required string**

```
"wanted1":"value1","wanted2":"value2"
```

Comment: What do you want with `"wanted_key":"unwanted"` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

**Script**

```
echo ',"wanted1":"value1","unwanted";"unwanted";"wanted2":"value2",' | sed 's/,//g; s/"unwanted"//g; s/;//g; s/""/","/g'
```

**Output**

```
"wanted1":"value1","wanted2":"value2"
```